# Write data points to InfluxDB2

Tags: grafana, influxdb, telegraf, influxdb-2

So I am trying to write a couple data points manually for testing purposes. I do see where in the InfluxDB2 UI, you can manually write data points to a bucket via the line protocol, upload a file, etc.  I know I will have to shutdown Telegraf so it is not writing data at the same time, so my manual data points can be viewed via Grafana.  But I am confused as to the structure to manually enter a couple data points.  For an example I want to write a couple data points where _value is lets say 25 vs 100.  I have changed some contents for privacy reasons.  Thanks for any assistance.  Here is a picture of some current
[example data points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cN0jy.jpg)  << an export in CSV from InfluxDB2 UI

When I try to enter data (see below) via Line Protocol the error msg is "invalid boolean"

```
service _value=25,_field=status,component=availability,metric_type=service,organization=BestBuy,service=Confluence,service_group=DevOps,status_message=OK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was missing double quotes around each value. Resolved.